# how to track user profile page views?

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to track page views to a user's profile page similar to what the core "statistics" module does for node page views.

I don't want to use profile2 for my site, otherwise I could probably use the statistics module.

Eventually I want to use the [Google Analytics](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module to track page views to cached pages as well.

I'm looking for a simple solution/workaround that I can use right now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [User Visits Advanced](http://drupal.org/project/user_visits_adv), and the [User Visits](http://drupal.org/project/user_visits) modules?

The User Visits Advanced module is a module that depends from the User Visits module. It is extremely useful for social networking sites that wish to provide their users with statistics about the number of time a user's profile page is being viewed, and by which users.

Comment: Instead of giving the same answer to two questions, you should flag the question as duplicate. Duplicate questions are closed.