# Get number of hits on user page into a view

Tags: users, nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to track user profile page views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22484/how-to-track-user-profile-page-views)

I would like to know how much time a user's page has been viewed, to sort my users by most total views.

My statistic module is active, and configured, but, i'm only able to retrieve the "content statistics: total views".

Is anyone have a solution?

Thanks,

-- Drupal 7, views 3